# Language specific input in RubyMine

Tags: input, character, rubymine

I just started to use RubyMine, but came across some really annoying problem..
Witch is, i cant input some language specific chars..
For example. My default language is Latvian, witch has some special chars, that english language dosnt have, like => (ā, č, ķ, ļ).
And, as it seems, RubyMine dosnt let me use these chars in editor. If i write them in, for example, notepad and copy/past in RubyMine, it works.. but i cant input them directly with my keyboard..

Note: these chars are in UTF-8 encoding :)

Hope, someone will be able to help me..

Answer (score 0):

It appears to be a bug specific to Latvian input with <kbd>AltGr</kbd> key (right <kbd>Alt</kbd>), we've [created a new issue for it](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-85942), star/vote to receive notifications about the progress.

Comment: it seems like that.. Anyway, i called to RubyMine support, and they couldnt help me. But they reported it as bug.

Comment: That was me who replied you and reported it as a bug.